# Generalization of Laplace's integral

Tags: definite-integrals, gaussian-integral

A generalization of the Gaussian integral
$$ \int_0^{\infty} e^{-\pi at^2} \, dt = \frac{1}{2\sqrt{a}}, \hspace{0.5cm} a>0 $$
is Laplace's integral:
$$ \int_0^{\infty} e^{-\pi at^2-\pi b/t^2} \, dt = \frac{1}{2\sqrt{a}}e^{-2\pi \sqrt{ab}}, \hspace{0.5cm} a,b>0. $$
Given that the Gaussian integral may be generalized to
$$ \int_0^{\infty} \cos(2\pi xt) e^{-\pi at^2} \, dt = \frac{1}{2\sqrt{a}}e^{-\pi x^2/a}, \hspace{0.5cm} a>0, \, x \in \mathbb{R}, $$
I am wondering if a similar 'cosine generalization' of Laplace's integral exists. That is, can we evaluate
$$ \int_0^{\infty} \cos(2\pi xt)e^{-\pi at^2-\pi b/t^2} \, dt, \hspace{0.5cm} a,b>0, \, x \in \mathbb{R} $$
in closed form? I have tried to do this by Taylor expanding the cosine and evaluating
$$ \int_0^{\infty} t^{2n} e^{-\pi at^2-\pi b/t^2} \, dt $$
for all $n \geq 0$ by differentiating Laplace's integral repeatedly with respect to $a$, but the formulas get complicated very quickly. Is there a nicer way to attempt this?

Comment: Laplace's integral is equivalent to the Gaussian integral by [Glasser's master theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4544140/695196). This nice symmetry is broken by the argument of the cosine being distinct from the argument of the exponential. Because of this, I doubt there's a clean solution.

Comment: However, by the same token, if you substitute the argument of the cosine by doing $t \to t - \sqrt{\frac{b}{a}}\frac{1}{t}$ then you again get a nice solution by Glasser's.